# How to match serialized value with single value LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello Am trying to creating an e-commerce site, basically, there is a popup "Select Location" When the site is loaded.when a location is selected, then a  location ID is Stored in session (location_id) through AJAX
And I have to fetch the categories acc. to the Location ID and also categories stored in Category(term) Table. I have stored a location ID in category Table (A Category May Belongs to Many Locations So I serialize the value and stored in the DB)

Here is my Query for fetching all categories with some conditions.

```
 $get_categories_data  =  Term::where(['type' => $cat_type, 'parent' => $cat_id, 'status' => 1])->get();
```

Now What I want is I have to fetch all categories acc to the session(location_id) value and also the location_id is serialized in the categories table

[image: Here is my Categories (terms) Table]

Comment: Search for laravel and "BelongsToMany" and see how people solve such relations in a normalized way.

Comment: Tried But Failed Can you Guide Me?? @PaulSpiegel

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: here what i have done `public function categories(){
  return $this->hasMany('shopist\Models\Term','location_id');
 }` i have created a categories function in Location Model It's only get categories when location id not serialized how to get categories when there is multi locations or serialized location ID values